# Database structure for posting tv series, each episode in specific season in sql

Tags: php, sql, database

So i was thinking and i can't figure it out.

I came up with idea of this.

```
table tv-shows (list of all tv shows)

id    show_title   
 1    Vampire Diaries
```

And then list of all episodes would go in one table

```
id    episode_title      episode_identifier      
 1    Vampire diaries    id from table tv-shows
 2    The walking dead   id from table tv-shows
```

**The problem**

I know i could do something like in php

```
"SELECT * FROM episodes WHERE episode_second_title = S1E5"
```

But i want to have new info and image posters and so on for each season.

*Im new to all of  this so don't mind my dumbiness*

And if idea is bad, please suggest a better <3 :)

Comment: I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this makes me think that you'll want three tables: Series, Episodes, and Seasons.

```
**Show**
ShowID(Primary Key)     ShowTitle

**Episodes**
ShowID(Foreign Key)     SeasonID     EpisodeID     EpisodeTitle     EpisodeDescription

**Seasons**
ShowID(Foreign Key)     SeasonID     SeasonDescription     SeasonPosterURL
```

This would have all three entities (Show, Episode, and Season) linked on ShowID, and would have Season and Episode linked on SeasonID. This way, each episode will have a unique combination of ShowID, SeasonID, and EpisodeId.

Granted, it might be better to break each show out into it's own schema instead of keeping all episodes of every show in one single table. Then you could have your tables organized like **my_tv_show_database.vampire_diaries.episodes** and **my_tv_show_database.vampire_diaries.seasons**

So your example query would be more like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_tv_show_database.vampire_diaries.episodes 
WHERE SeasonID=1 AND EpisodeID=15;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'll try this.

Comment: Why would you want individual tables for each tv series? Episodes (no matter the tv series they belong to) have the same properties and are a single Entity. It adds nothing to the design and could complicate the code.